# White lines in Grid View, Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to develop a Sudoku app. I have created a list for all positions in the game field. To display the fields I used a grid view. However, I have the problem that white lines appear in the grid view and I don't understand why. In the attached image you can see this in more detail.

Here is my code for the grid view:

```
  GridView.builder(
    itemCount: gameFields.length,
    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 9,
    ),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
      color: Colors.lightGreen,
      child: Center(
        child: Text("${index + 1}"),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem myself, it was related to the size the grid had available. I had set width and height to 500. if you calculate 500 / 9 you get 55.5 period. This creates a white area at certain intervals.

Answer (score 1):

wrap the GridView.builder(), in a container and give background color green it is not a perfect solution but i think it will help you